# Android App keep crashing when building from Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I'm working on an android app in Eclipse, fairly new to this. I am trying to build from the iBeacon Android SDK and everytime i build it keep crashing. here is what my logcat looks like

```
03-13 17:42:31.374: W/dalvikvm(9100): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41768898)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.estimote.examples.demos/com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity" on path: /data/app/com.estimote.examples.demos-2.apk
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity" on path: /data/app/com.estimote.examples.demos-2.apk
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
03-13 17:42:31.384: E/AndroidRuntime(9100):     ... 11 more
03-13 17:42:45.317: I/Process(9100): Sending signal. PID: 9100 SIG: 9
```

And this is what my manifest looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.estimote.examples.demos"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="18"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

  <!-- Needed permissions in order to scan for beacons. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

  <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

  <application
      android:label="Estimote Demos"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

    <activity
        android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity"
        android:label="Estimote Demos"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.ListBeaconsActivity"
        android:label="Select Beacon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.DistanceBeaconActivity"
              android:label="Distance Demo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity"
              android:label="Notify Demo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.CharacteristicsDemoActivity"
              android:label="Characteristics Demo"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <!-- Estimote service responsible for scanning beacons. -->
    <service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
             android:exported="false"/>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I downloaded the SDK straight from here

https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK

and am just trying to get it to run on a device. Also I don't have a SIM card in the phone. not sure if that is the issue.

The exact error I get is  "Unfortunately "APP NAME" has stopped"

Comment: Your manifest is mangled. The `uses-sdk` tag has garbage in it.

Comment: I tried changing it to this but still no luck. Any further insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

  <uses-sdk 
      android:name="com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity"
      android:minSdkVersion="18"
      android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: You should look at this line: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.examples.demos.AllDemosActivity" on path: /data/app/com.estimote.examples.demos-2.apk` Some reason the activity class cannot be found...

Comment: What version of the ADT are you using? This error started occurring in a lot of places some time ago when I think ADT 22 came out? Just make sure you have the updated version of the ADT. If that doesnt work, we can try looking into other stuff

Comment: I'm using Build: v22.3.0-887826

I just feel like i have something improperly set up and cant figure it out.

Comment: Either you do not have such an Activity in the build path of your project, it is being removed at install because it has unavailable dependencies, or it is being renamed to an obfuscated name by a misconfigured use of proguard during the build.